# How to access a function's data inside an array using Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, function, constants

Good day,
I have a simple question (I hope).  How do I access the array of "LOCATION_LOOKUP_DATA" within the following code?

```
(Wonder.Way.Communities = function() {
    var CONSTANTS = {
        LOCATION_LOOKUP_DATA :["Yonkers (10710)","Yorktown Heights (10598)"]
        }
    }
)
```

I am trying to replace the array of LOCATION_LOOKUP_DATA with new data so I need to access that array.  Here are some of the checks I've tried, and the results

```
     alert($(Wonder.Way.Communities).data()); -returns [object Object]
     alert(Wonder.Way.Communities[0]); - returns [undefined]
     alert($(Wonder.Way.Communities).CONSTANTS[0]; returns [Cannot read property '0' of undefined]
```

Comment: Your code's syntax is incorrect, which may make it difficult to usefully answer the question. Please correct the first codeblock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an accessor function at the same scope level as CONSTANTS, which will have access to the CONSTANTS object.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to JQuery.  How do I create the accessor function?  Do I create a function that returns(constants)?

Comment: Exactly as you said, you'd create a function that would return CONSTANTS.  Since the function would exist in the same scope as CONSTANTS, it would be able to return it. You'd just need to make sure that your Wonder.Way.Communities internal functions can also be accessed. It looks like you're using it in an anonymous way, so I think you should consider making it more like a jQuery plugin, which would give you an architecture to reference for that kind of access to internal methods. Check out jQuery Plugin Design in google for sample architectures that may help in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You cant as the code currently stands. you need to make it accessible outside the scope of the function somehow.

Comment: Thank you.  I thought this was a closure since I have a function inside a function. I read that a closure's functions are accessible outside the global function that's way I thought I could access the data.